# Sending Strings Queue to Clipboard in python

Tags: python, ocr, xclip

I am writing a program that runs in background and check's for file changes in a folder if any new Image file arrives into that folder it will read text from that Image with the help of tesseract OCR Engine.Images contains Adresses of Employees.python program splits that Adress into individual list.

I want to put each address section into clipboard one after other.So If I press Ctrl+V First Section will pasted.Next time if i press Ctrl+v Next section will pasted like wise.

Here is the Code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import commands,os
global vdir,outfile
global prev
vdir="Vilvin"
out="Output"
a=os.listdir(vdir)
prev=len(a)
whcount=0
stat_dict={'NEW HRMPSHIRE': 'NEW HAMPSHIRE', 'VERMONT': 'VERMONT', 'LOUISIRNR': 'LOUISIANA', 'CRLIFORNIR': 'CALIFORNIA', 'MISSISSIPPI': 'MISSISSIPPI', 'PENNSYLVRNIR': 'PENNSYLVANIA', 'MONTRNR': 'MONTANA', 'GEORGIR': 'GEORGIA', 'WRSHINGTON': 'WASHINGTON', 'NEW YORK': 'NEW YORK', 'MRRYLRND': 'MARYLAND', 'IOWR': 'IOWA', 'SOUTH DRKOTR': 'SOUTH DAKOTA', 'VIRGINIR': 'VIRGINIA', 'FLORIDR': 'FLORIDA', 'MRINE': 'MAINE', 'NEBRRSKR': 'NEBRASKA', 'RLRSKR': 'ALASKA', 'ILLINOIS': 'ILLINOIS', 'CONNECTICUT': 'CONNECTICUT', 'TENNESSEE': 'TENNESSEE', 'NEW MEXICO': 'NEW MEXICO', 'COLORRDO': 'COLORADO', 'DELRWRRE': 'DELAWARE', 'HRWRII': 'HAWAII', 'NORTH CRROLINR': 'NORTH CAROLINA', 'UTRH': 'UTAH', 'RLRBRMR': 'ALABAMA', 'MICHIGRN': 'MICHIGAN', 'RRKRNSRS': 'ARKANSAS', 'NEW JERSEY': 'NEW JERSEY', 'MISSOURI': 'MISSOURI', 'OREGON': 'OREGON', 'WYOMING': 'WYOMING', 'OHIO': 'OHIO', 'WISCONSIN': 'WISCONSIN', 'MINNESOTR': 'MINNESOTA', 'KRNSRS': 'KANSAS', 'RHODE ISLRND': 'RHODE ISLAND', 'WEST VIRGINIR': 'WEST VIRGINIA', 'IDRHO': 'IDAHO', 'OKLRHOMR': 'OKLAHOMA', 'KENTUCKY': 'KENTUCKY', 'RRIZONR': 'ARIZONA', 'NEVRDR': 'NEVADA', 'INDIRNR': 'INDIANA', 'MRSSRCHUSETTS': 'MASSACHUSETTS', 'SOUTH CRROLINR': 'SOUTH CAROLINA', 'NORTH DRKOTR': 'NORTH DAKOTA', 'TEXRS': 'TEXAS'}
while True:
    instant=os.listdir(vdir)
    if(len(instant)>prev):
        print "File Change Detected...."
        r=commands.getoutput('ls -ct1 '+vdir+' | head -1')
        print "Most recent file = %s " %(r)
        r=r.replace("(","\(")
        r=r.replace(")","\)")
        r=r.replace(" ","\ ")
        os.system("tesseract "+vdir+"/"+r+" "+out+"/"+"Output")
        result=commands.getoutput("awk -F: '{ print $2 $3 }' "+out+"/"+"Output.txt")
        res=result.split("\n")
        state=res[0].split("State")
        profile=res[1].split("Pro?ile")
        applicant=state[0].strip().replace("R","A")
        state=state[1].strip()
        state=stat_dict[state]
        sid=profile[0].strip()
        profile=profile[1].strip().replace("R","A")
        sec=res[3].strip().replace("R","A")
        a=commands.getoutput("echo \""+applicant+"\" | xclip -verbose -selection clipboard")
        b=commands.getoutput("echo \""+state+"\" | xclip -verbose -selection clipboard")
        c=commands.getoutput("echo \""+sid+"\" | xclip -verbose -selection clipboard")
        d=commands.getoutput("echo \""+profile+"\" | xclip -verbose -selection clipboard")
        e=commands.getoutput("echo \""+sec+"\" | xclip -verbose -selection clipboard")
        print "Applicant : "+applicant+"\nState : "+state+"\nStaff ID : "+sid+"\nProfile : "+profile+"\nSEC : "+sec+"\n"
        prev=len(instant)
    else:
        whcount=whcount+1
        print "While Loop Count : "+str(whcount)+"\n"
        os.system("sleep 2")
```

One thing I forgot is this program always runs in background & the terminal windows is minimised so we have to get Key presses on whole Xsession & GUI Apps..whenever Ctrl+V triggered in any application we should detect that ...Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is it timed, or do you want the next selection to trigger when "Ctrl + V" is pressed?

Comment: Yes i want to trigger next Selection when Ctrl+v Pressed...

Comment: Yeah...I just Checked it..it's just taking letter from terminal but my requirement is wherever he press Ctrl+v (GUI Apps & X Session) it should detect like keylogger...

Comment: Wrote you a new answer :)

Comment: I want it for Linux ... not for Windows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so, here is how this goes:

```
import time,os,win32api
from msvcrt import getch

def addToClipBoard(text):
    command = 'echo ' + text.strip() + '| clip'
    os.system(command)


def testpress(key):
    return (win32api.GetKeyState(key) & (1 << 7)) != 0

key = 17 #ctrl key
key2= ord('V')
copy=1

while True:
    keydown = testpress(key)
    key2down = testpress(key2)
    if keydown and key2down:
        print 'CtrlV pressed!'
        if copy==1:
          addToClipBoard('Foo')
        elif copy==2:
            addToClipBoard('Shoo')
        elif copy==3:
            addToClipBoard('THA END')
        if copy>3:
            exit(1)
        copy+=1
    time.sleep(0.10)
```

I got the code for testing the keypress using win32api from another answer, then put it all together to do what you wanted it to :)

Comment: Daw, come on! I worked so hard on that. lol. You could upvote my answer ;)